# javascript stack overflow while drawing images

Tags: javascript, image, html, firefox, canvas

I am simply loading a ton of images (about 5000) into "new Image()" objects and draw them each in a canvas by calling canvas.drawImage(image, 0, 0);

This works totally fine with IE10, but as soon as I am using Firefox I will get an stack overflow error, because somehow the memory usage of the Firefox rises and rises till it overflows. Does anyone have an idea why? I think the GC dont really collect my images after drawing them into the canvas. Even when I am using 100 Image objects and just cycle the src of the Image objects before drawing them, the memory usage rises and rises. I will test Chrome and Safari soon, but still need a solution for that, cause everyone is using "the best browser" Firefox.

EDIT:

```
function play() {
    //calculated iLag here
    //calculated wondow.FrameCtr here
    var iFrameRate = Math.round(1000 / 25);
    var oImage = new Image();
    oImage.onload = function () {
        renderImage(this);
    }
    //window.Video is an array of window.URL.createObjectURL(data) (about 500 items)
    oImage.src = window.Video[window.FrameCtr];
    oImage = null;
    setTimeout(
            function () {
                play()
            }, iFrameRate - iLag
        );

function renderImage(oImage) {
  $("#video")[0].getContext("2d").drawImage(oImage, 0, 0);
}
```

I do loop this video (500 items, 25fps) 10 times, and ff isn't even able to play it once, cause of stack overflow.
As I mentioned before it is working fine with IE10 and works even better with Chrome, so I don't think the problem here is the recursion. Is there any other way to get binary data into in canvas, than using an Image object and setting the src?

Comment: Which version of firefox are you using, I am asking this because this was a bug in previous versions.

Comment: Stack overflow typically means you have an infinite (or at least very deep) recursion.  What does your code actually look like?

Comment: I am using FF12.0.
Code actually looks like:
    var oImage = new Image();
    oImage.onload = function () {
        renderImage(this);
    }
    oImage.src = window.Video[window.FrameCtr];
where renderImage(this) is just calling drawImage(image, 0, 0) and window.Video is an array of createObjectUrl(binary data) .. this code is called with setTimeout about 15 - 25 times per second.

Comment: update the code in the question itself here it is highly unreadable on the comment

Answer (score 0):

It is already noted as a bug in Firefox. You can see the [bug report here](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=405584). It is showing a last modified date of 2010-09-17 but I am not sure has it been resolved in newer version or what.

But I guess newer version of Firefox should not have that problem.

Comment: The bug you're linking to was fixed in Firefox 2.0, back in late 2007.

Comment: I am using FF 12.0 and this is the latest I guess?